# Labeling for Highchart Funnel Visualization

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I am trying to create a funnel visualization that would visualization the number of guests and also percent of prior visit for 3 categories of consumers: 1 Visit, 2 Visits, 3+ Visits.

Right now I have 2 labels for each category (sticking out to the right hand side) but I want 1 label for each category sticking out on the right hand side stating both the # of Guests and Percent of Prior Visit. I also want a box-shaped label for each block of the funnel so that when you hover over it it looks like:

```
[CATEGORY]

Percent of Prior Visit: [VALUE]

Guests: [VALUE]
```

Right now, the box-shaped label when I hover over the block just shows Percent of Prior visit. So I want the box to be fixed and the label to the right hand side to be just 1 per block. I hope this makes sense. How would I do something like this? Thanks in advance.

My code is at: https://jsfiddle.net/ug4rc6pn/150/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the style you tried with earlier makes this easier. That is, setting both value and percentage in the same series, like this:

```
 series: [{
  name: 'Guests',
  data: [{
      y: 352000,
      yPercentage: 100,
      name: '1 Visit',
      color: "#ff0000",
    },
    ...
  ]
}]
```

You can then format your datalabel like this:

```
dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
  format: '<b>{point.name}</b> <br/>{point.y:,.0f} ({point.yPercentage} %)',
  ...
}
```

And your tooltip like this:

```
tooltip: {
  headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px"><b>{point.key}</b></span><br/>',
  pointFormat: 'Percent of Prior Visit: {point.yPercentage} % <br/>Guests: {point.y:,.0f}  '
}
```

Which gives you this:

[image]

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'funnel',
    //Only for Pie Charts
    options3d: {
      enabled: false, // change to true to activate 3D
      alpha: 40,
      beta: 40,
      depth: 100,
    },
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Guest Return Funnel'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    funnel: {
      depth: 100
    },
    series: {
      events: {
        legendItemClick: function() {
          $.each(this.chart.series, function(i, serie) {
            if (serie.visible)
              serie.hide();
            else
              serie.show();
          });
          return false;
        }
      },
      shadow: true,
      allowPointSelect: true,
      borderWidth: 18,
      animation: {
        duration: 400
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '<b>{point.name}</b> <br/>{point.y:,.0f} ({point.yPercentage} %)',
        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black',
        softConnector: true,
        crop: false
      },
      center: ['50%', '50%'],
      neckWidth: '40%',
      neckHeight: '0%',
      width: '65%',
      height: '100%',
      tooltip: {
       headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px"><b>{point.key}</b></span><br/>',
       pointFormat: 'Percent of Prior Visit: {point.yPercentage} % <br/>Guests: {point.y:,.0f}  '
      }
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true
  },
  series: [{
      name: 'Guests',
      data: [{
          y: 352000,
          yPercentage: 100,
          name: '1 Visit',
          color: "#ff0000",
        },
        {
          y: 88000,
          yPercentage: 25,
          name: '2 Visits',
          color: "#FFA500",
        },
        {
          y: 42000,
          yPercentage: 48,
          name: '3+ Visits',
          color: "#32CD32"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
/*    
series: [{
name: 'Guests',
name2: 'Percent of Prior Visit',
data: [{
y:352000,
name: '1 Visit',
color: "#ff0000",
y2: 100,
name2: 'Percent of Prior Visit'
},
{
y: 88000,
name: '2 Visits',
color: "#FFA500",
y2: 25,
name2: 'Percent of Prior Visit',
},
{
y: 42000,
name: '3+ Visits',
color:"#32CD32",
y2: 48,
name2: 'Percent of Prior Visit'
}
]
}]
});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js">


</script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/funnel.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 410px; max-width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

**JSFiddle working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/org6quk9/

Comment: Thank you. I have actually reformatted the funnel so that the label is centered and I implemented a scaling algorithm so that the visualization visualizes small values. However, the way I put in the data for the series is different now. How would I be able to do what you just did but for the new data format I have now? If it's not possible or very difficult to do it with the data format that is like [label, value] how would I do it with the one I used earlier while still having the algorithm work? You'll know what I mean when you open up my code. It is at http://jsfiddle.net/69eey/92/